# how to change the response body from apche-apisix?

Tags: apache-apisix

i need to parse json from backend and modify it, for example remove urls for pagination, the consumer don't want it. And i can't modify this in backend.
how to do this with response-rewrite plugin. getting response from backend in variable and do json parsing...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure filters in this plugin to replace certain content

ref: https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/response-rewrite/

[image]